# Get Farm Features from SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am attempting to get a list of Farm Features from a SharePoint 2010 Central Admin site.  The issue I am having is that I have only succeeded in pulling back **Site** Features.  The following code is what I am currently working with:

```
foreach (SPFeature feature in SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local.Features)
{
    string featureName = feature.Definition.DisplayName;
    if (featureName != null)
    {
        XElement newItem = new XElement("Item", featureName);
        infoTree.Add(newItem);
    }

}
```

I have also tried using `SPFarm.Local.FeatureDefinitions`  as follows:

```
foreach (SPFeatureDefinition feature in SPFarm.Local.FeatureDefinitions)
{
    string featureName = feature.DisplayName;
if (featureName != null)
    {
        XElement newItem = new XElement("Item", featureName);
        infoTree.Add(newItem);
    }
```

but to no avail.  The next avenue I am approaching is using `SPFeatureCollection`. Is there a better approach I can take to this issue?  Basically I'm just looking for some clues as I have not gotten anything out of `SPFeatureCollection` just yet.

**EDIT**
I have been messing around with

```
SPFeatureCollection featureCollect = SPContext.Current.Site.Features
```

but so far I am having an issue with `SPContext` returning null.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sorry, I phrased it how I generally start Google queries.  Non-intentional violation

Comment: Not a problem. [so] puts the first tag into the title for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the right track with the second example.  The part that you are missing is checking the feature scope.  SPFarm.Local.FeatureDefinitions is bringing back a collection of all of the features defined in the farm (a collection of SPFeatureDefinition objects).  From there, you can check the Scope property of the SPFeatureDefinition object to narrow it down to just the Farm scoped features.

Example:

```
foreach (SPFeatureDefinition feature in SPFarm.Local.FeatureDefinitions)
{
    if (feature.Scope = "Farm")
    {
        string featureName = feature.DisplayName;
        if (featureName != null)
        {
            XElement newItem = new XElement("Item", featureName);
            infoTree.Add(newItem);
        }
    }
```

Additional MSDN reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfeaturedefinition_members.aspx) for the available properties of the SPFeatureDefinition object.

Comment: Ah yes, I completely forgot to look into Scope settings.  Thanks for the suggestion/examples.  I will start playing with this!

Comment: Scopes were indeed the answer!  It did not like `features.Scope = "Farm"` but declaring a scope prior to the if and then comparing: `features.Scope.Equals(scopeSelect)` did the trick.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry about the syntax error on my part.  I had used a PowerShell script when double checking it.  That script looked like this:  $farm = get-spfarm;

foreach ($feature in $farm.FeatureDefinitions) {
    if ($feature.Scope -eq "Farm") {
        write-host $feature.name $feature.FeatureDefinitionScope
    }
}
Glad that worked for you though!

Comment: No problem!  It kept me from just copy/pasting and I learned a little bit more.